# How to destroy VC after adding to UIWindow?

Tags: memory-leaks, uiviewcontroller, xctest, uiwindow

For certain types of tests, I need the view controller to be inside a UIWindow. The UIWindow itself is never shown. I'm having trouble destroying the view controller.

Say we have

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    deinit {
        print("MyVC bye-bye")
    }
}

class MyWindow: UIWindow {
    deinit {
        print("MyWindow bye-bye")
    }
}
```

Now in a test suite, I can make both objects and they'll be deallocated.

```
class MyTests: XCTestCase {
    func test() {
        let vc = MyViewController()
        let window = MyWindow()
    }
}
```

In the console output, I see

```
MyWindow bye-bye
MyVC bye-bye
```

But if I add the following line to the test, neither object is destroyed.

```
        window.addSubview(vc.view)
```

The window itself may be cleaned up later by the autorelease pool. But my main concern is that the view controller isn't destroyed.

I tried doing

```
        vc.view.removeFromSuperview()
```

but that's not enough.

Comment: If I create this scenario in a brand new Xcode project (using the Single View App template), I see the logging output suggesting both the window and then view controller are getting deallocated as expected. Perhaps there is something specific about your project configuration?

Comment: Ahh, I didn't check the complete logs. Turns out we're both right. It is being deallocated, but only after the test runner has completely shut down. So that gave me a clue, which led to an answer…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pumping the run loop gives the autorelease pool a kick, so that no objects linger after the test concludes. If the objects are purely local to the test, place the objects in the autorelease pool and do the pump:

```
func test() {
    autoreleasepool {
        let vc = MyViewController()
        let window = MyWindow()
        window.addSubview(vc.view)
    }
    RunLoop.current.run(until: Date())
}
```

But in most test suites, the view controller is part of the test fixture. In that case, pump the loop after releasing the fixture.

```
override func tearDown() {
    vc = nil
    RunLoop.current.run(until: Date())
    super.tearDown()
}
```

Comment: wouldn't wrapping the particular test case body in `autoreleasepool` work as well? This wouldn't affect all the remaining test cases (as `tearDown` does somehow)

Comment: I tried that and was unsuccessful. But I didn't add the run loop pump after it, so the pool probably wasn't triggered. Let me try again and update.

Comment: I have the same problem, and It tried this and it doesn't seem to make a difference.